# What Stack Exchange sites and features are not available in the Android app?

Tags: support, android-app

I just installed the app, and noticed that not all sites are present there, and are not directly accessible in the app.

My question is, what are the sites which not available on the app directly?

As This would be informative to the other users.

Comment: The question is there but I don't thinks there's an answer to the request.

Comment: That doesn't matter for a feature request. Also, if you have a new question, you should open a new question, not edit your existing one. Though I think the answer is simply *all sites in Area 51 + Stack Overflow Jobs + Stack Overflow Documentation*.

Comment: @Glorfindel well, since it's a dupe and closed anyway, it doesn't really matter, think it's legit to change. Helped OP to do that properly now. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes, no real harm, but chameleon questions are so frowned upon that it is better no to have any exceptions to this rule. Still, voted to reopen - the question itself might have some real value after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sites/subsites are not available from the app:

- [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)
- [Stack Overflow Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs)
- [Stack Overflow Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) (and as a general rule, everything that's still in its Beta phase)
- [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com)

Some parts of the site are only available via an in-app browser and do not offer a native experience:

- Chat (only in the iOS app; there is a link in the app navigation to each site's respective chat)

  - note that it's particularly hard to get into the chatrooms under chat.stackexchange.com, like [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), because you can't edit the current URL of the in-app browser
- By following links in posts, you can open almost any part of the site in an in-app browser, like the help center or the election pages (or the sites mentioned above).

Comment: Can also say "only sites listed [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites) are avaiable and fully supported in the app."